# Is it possible to set another user's password in Meteor if you have admin privileges?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, change-password

I am now trying to set another user's password in Meteor admin page.

Here is my code.

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateUserPassword: function(userId, password) {
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.user()

    if (!loggedInUser ||
        !(Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['admin'], 'default_group')) || (loggedInUser._id == userId) ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Access denied")
    }

    return Accounts.setPassword(userId, password);
  }
});
```

But when I run this code, I get Accounts.setPassword is undefined error.

I added accounts-password and accounts-base packages, but it still shows undefined error, so I suspect if the Accounts.setPassword is not supported anymore.

Please help me how to handle this problem!

Comment: The `Accounts.setPassword` function can only be called from the server. Are you getting the error on your browser console?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the error on browser console. so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accounts.setPassword` is a *server-only* function in `Meteor`. If you are getting the error in your browser console it is because your `updateUserPassword` method is declared in `lib/` folder or somewhere similar and can be accessed by both **client-side** and server-side.

Usually, it is desirable for `Meteor.methods` to be declared in `lib/` folder in order to take advantage of Meteor's [Latency Compensation](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/advanced-latency-compensation/) technique (also called Method Simulation).

In your case that is not desirable because `Accounts.setPassword` is *server-only*.

---

**Solution 1:**

You can use `Meteor.isClient` and `Meteor.isServer` to determine which code to run where. (You can also use `this.isSimulation`).

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateUserPassword: function(userId, password) {
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.user()

    if (!loggedInUser ||
        !(Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['admin'], 'default_group')) || (loggedInUser._id == userId) ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Access denied")
    }

    if(Meteor.isServer) {
        return Accounts.setPassword(userId, password);
    } else if(Meteor.isClient) {
        // do something else
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Solution 2:**

You can declare the `Meteor.methods` on the server-side by placing the file in the server-only `server/` folder, or placing the whole of the `Meteor.methods` declaration within a `if(Meteor.isServer) { ... }` check.

This should be used when latency compensation is not needed.